# OpenNLP how create a model to parser-chunking

Tags: java, parsing, opennlp, text-chunking

I'm trying to create a parser-chunking in Portuguese with OpenNLP. But I'm not having success. 
I think that it is necessary two files to create a model:

- One training file with train.all extension and  the format:

  ```
  (TOP (S (NP-SBJ (DT Some) )(VP (VBP say) (NP (NNP November) ))(. .) ))
  (TOP (S (NP-SBJ (PRP I) )(VP (VBP say) (NP (CD 1992) ))(. .) ('' '') ))
  ```
- One rules file with the headRules name. My file contains these rules taken from the internet.

  ```
  20 ADJP 0 NNS QP NN $ ADVP JJ VBN VBG ADJP JJR NP JJS DT FW RBR RBS SBAR RB 
  15 ADVP 1 RB RBR RBS FW ADVP TO CD JJR JJ IN NP JJS NN
  5 CONJP 1 CC RB IN
  2 FRAG 1 
  2 INTJ 0 
  4 LST 1 LS :
  19 NAC 0 NN NNS NNP NNPS NP NAC EX $ CD QP PRP VBG JJ JJS JJR ADJP FW
  8 PP 1 IN TO VBG VBN RP FW
  2 PRN 1 
  3 PRT 1 RP
  ```

I use this command to generate the model en-parser-chunking.bin

```
$ Bin / OpenNLP ParserTrainer -encoding ISO-8859-1 -lang en -parserType CHUNKING -headRules head_rules -data train.all -model en-parser-chunking.bin
```

So, I use this model en-parser-chunking.bin to process the parser. Following the code:

```
ParserModel modelParse = new ParserModel(parserStream);
Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(modelParse);
Parse Parses [] = ParserTool.parseLine ("Some say Novembro", parser, 1);
```

When run the code, the following error occurs:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/ProjetoCMBuilder] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1] with root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at opennlp.tools.parser.treeinsert.Parser.advanceParses(Parser.java:346)
    at opennlp.tools.parser.AbstractBottomUpParser.parse(AbstractBottomUpParser.java:311)
    at opennlp.tools.parser.AbstractBottomUpParser.parse(AbstractBottomUpParser.java:365)
    at opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool.parseLine(ParserTool.java:77)
    at ProjetoCMBuilder.service.LibOpenNLPServiceBean.processarTexto(LibOpenNLPServiceBean.java:78)
    at ProjetoCMBuilder.controller.ProcessController.getAllPropositionPt(ProcessController.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

How can I create a model parser-chunking.bin?